# Промежуточная таблица для связи трёх таблиц

Tags: php, laravel

Есть три таблицы:
`category`
id, title

`attributes`
id, name

`values`
id, name, attribute_id

И связывающая таблица:
`cat_attr_val`
category_id, attribute_id, value_id

Как реализовать модель для последующей работы с этой таблицей?
Можно ли будет добавлять записи в эту pivot таблицу с помощью `model->pivotmodel()->attach(val)`  ?
Или записи в эту таблицу нужно будет добавлять с помощью `DB::insert` ?

Comment: `attach/sync/toggle` методы для добавления записей отношений **Many-to-Many**

Comment: @E_K, эти методы `attach/sync/toggle` работают только для связи двух таблиц

Comment: В методе **attach** вы можете передавать доп. данные которые для pivot  таблицы. Способа из коробки для работы с тремя таблицами по примеру двух из **Many-to-Many** я не нашел. [Единственное](https://www.slideshare.net/AlexanderWeissman1/hacking-laravel-custom-relationships-with-eloquent), что нашел по этой теме.

Answer (score 1):

Да всё же просто.
category к attributes - Это Many-to-Many
attributes к values - Это Many-to-Many

Какое отношение values имеет к category? Вы их легко сможете получить через attributes.